# Left join does not return all rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 178 rows on one table and 179 on the other for an specific order, but no matter what I do I can not get the SQL query to show me the 179 rows, it only shows me 178 rows.

```
SELECT 
    rl.po, rl.item_id, rl.pieces_received, 
    ol.order_id, ol.item_id, ol.pieces_shipped 
FROM 
    receipt_lines rl
LEFT JOIN 
    hi_order_lines ol ON rl.item_id = ol.item_id
WHERE  
    ol.order_id = 'TR0202379' 
    AND rl.po = 'TR0202379'
```

I have also tried

```
SELECT 
    rl.po, rl.item_id, rl.pieces_received,
    ol.order_id, ol.item_id, ol.pieces_shipped 
FROM 
    receipt_lines rl
LEFT JOIN 
    hi_order_lines ol ON rl.item_id = ol.item_id
                      AND ol.order_id = 'TR0202379' 
                      AND rl.po = 'TR0202379'
```

Among other variations of the query, but I don't know what can be wrong.

Just adding some data for visualization purposes..

```
 PO                         item_id        pieces_received  order_id                item_id                 pieces_shipped    
TR0202379               CM504438-BLK-  M                77  TR0202379               CM504438-BLK-  M                77
TR0202379               CM504438-BLK-XXL                14  TR0202379               CM504438-BLK-XXL                14
TR0202379               CM504438-BLK-  S                32  TR0202379               CM504438-BLK-  S                32
TR0202379               CM504438-LDN- XL                2   TR0202379               CM504438-LDN- XL                2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you have where predicates referencing a table that is left joined it is turning that left join into an inner join. Try moving "ol.order_id='TR0202379'" to your join condition instead.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you referring to something like my second example? if not can you explain please with an example?

Comment: This: `ol.order_id='TR0202379'` ensures you get only rows where this is true. Move that to the `ON` clause.

Comment: I did try that, look at my second example

ON rl.item_id=ol.item_id
AND  ol.order_id='TR0202379' AND rl.po='TR0202379'

If I just do ON ol.order_id='TR0202379' AND rl.po='TR0202379'
I get  over 4,000 lines and that is not correct either.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, you haven't said which table contains the most rows so I've given you a couple of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there with your second example, give this a go;

```
SELECT 
    rl.po, rl.item_id, rl.pieces_received,
    ol.order_id, ol.item_id, ol.pieces_shipped 
FROM 
    receipt_lines rl
LEFT JOIN 
    hi_order_lines ol ON rl.item_id = ol.item_id
                      AND ol.order_id = 'TR0202379' 
WHERE rl.po = 'TR0202379'
```

This is assuming that Receipt_Lines is the table with 179 rows. If it is hi_order_lines then you'll have to switch these tables round (I really dislike right joins) like this;

```
SELECT 
    rl.po, rl.item_id, rl.pieces_received,
    ol.order_id, ol.item_id, ol.pieces_shipped 
FROM 
    hi_order_lines ol

LEFT JOIN receipt_lines rl
     ON rl.item_id = ol.item_id
                      AND rl.po = 'TR0202379'
WHERE ol.order_id = 'TR0202379'
```

Comment: That's great. Out of curiosity, is it the first or second one that's working for you?

Comment: The second worked.

I wonder if there is a way to write this query regardless of where the extra line is, because I need to use it to compare the two tables.

Comment: take a look at full outer join, that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the id of all records on both tables is TR0202379 then it must be that the left table hi_order_lines is the table with 178 rows.  Try using right join.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using LEFT JOIN, you are always going to get 178 rows because you're joining on 'receipt_lines' which is the left table in your case, LEFT JOIN doesn't include null values for the left table, instead you might want to try RIGHT JOIN, that would give you the remaining row with nulls for receipt_lines.

```
SELECT rl.po,rl.item_id, rl.pieces_received,ol.order_id,ol.item_id,ol.pieces_shipped FROM receipt_lines rl
RIGHT JOIN hi_order_lines ol
ON rl.item_id=ol.item_id
WHERE  ol.order_id='TR0202379' AND rl.po='TR0202379'
```

or you could switch your query as follows:

```
SELECT rl.po,rl.item_id, rl.pieces_received,ol.order_id,ol.item_id,ol.pieces_shipped FROM hi_order_lines ol
LEFT JOIN receipt_lines rl 
ON rl.item_id=ol.item_id
WHERE  ol.order_id='TR0202379' AND rl.po='TR0202379'
```

Comment: could you figure out what is the missing row?